# Let n be a natural number greater than $1$. Prove that there exists a natural number m greater than $n ^ n$ such $n + m$ divides $n ^ {m} - m ^{n}$

Tags: solution-verification, integers

Let n be a natural number greater than $1$. Prove that there exists a natural number m greater than $n ^ n$ such that: $n + m$ divides
$n ^ {m} - m ^{n}$

\begin{align*}
&(n^m - m^n) = n^m(1 - \frac{m^n}{n^m}) \\
&\text{Since } n > 1, \text{ then } n^m > 1, \text{ so } (n^m - m^n) = n^m(1 - \frac{m^n}{n^m}) \text{ is a multiple of } n. \\
\\
&(n^m - m^n) \equiv \binom{m}{0} n^m - \binom{m}{n} m^n \pmod{n + 1} \\
&\text{We can use the Binomial Theorem to expand }(n^m - m^n)\text{ as shown:} \\
&\qquad (n^m - m^n) = \binom{m}{0} n^m - \binom{m}{1} n^{m - 1} m + \binom{m}{2} n^{m - 2} m^2 - \binom{m}{3} n^{m - 3} m^3 + \dotsb - \binom{m}{n} m^n \\
&\text{We can see that all of the terms in this expansion, except for the first and last terms, are divisible by } n + 1. \\
&\text{This is because each term contains a factor of } n, \text{ and } n+1 \text{ does not divide } n. \\
&\text{Therefore, the remainder when }(n^m - m^n)\text{ is divided by } n + 1 \text{ is equal to difference of } 1st \text{ and } last \text{ terms.} \\
\\
&Remainder = \binom{m}{0} n^m - \binom{m}{n} m^n \\
&\text{Factoring out } n^n \text{ here, we get} \\
&Remainder = n^n (\binom{m}{0} - \binom{m}{n}) \\
\\
&\text{Now, we can use the following combinatorial identity:} \\
&\qquad \binom{m}{0} - \binom{m}{n} = \binom{m - 1}{n - 1} \\
&\text{We want to choose a value for } m \text{ such that } n^n\binom{m-1}{n-1} \text{ is divisible by } n+1. \\
&\text{We can do this by choosing a value for } m \text{ that is greater than } n^n, \text{ such that } n-1 \text{ is divisible by } n+1. \\
&\text{For eg. } m = 1 + n + n^n, \text{ then } m-1=n + n^n \text{ and this is divisble by } n+1. \\
&\text{Therefore, } n+m \text{ divides } (n^m-m^n).
\end{align*}

Comment: $$\text{Why would you type like this?}$$

Comment: @Shaun I'm not good at latex

Comment: I took a look at your "code" and it is overkill. Just type "normally" and use dollar signs to enclose math. I don't think you need all that text, align, \, & etc.  Look at other questions if needed. If you write a question and it does not look good to you, just tweak it a little adding breaks with blank lines.

Comment: There are numerous statements that do not make sense, so please review and edit again. EG 1/ From the start, $n^m \times X$ need not be a multiple of $n$, esp if $X$ is a fraction with a denominator of $n^{m+1}$. That's like saying $ 3 = 2 \times 3/2$ hence is even. 2/ Why is ${m\choose n} \equiv 1 \pmod{n+1}$? That this holds for all $m$ seems very unlikely. 3/ When you "factoring out $n^n$", you seem to indicate that $n^n = n^m = m^n $Why? 4/ Did you invent that combinatorial identity? Note that the LHS is negative but the RHS is positive.

Comment: @KalpeshDesai FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%2Bm%5Cmid%20n%5Em-m%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24m%5Cgt%20n%5En%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Exist big m such that...](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1220643p6101949), which states the problem is from "Serbia Math Olympiad $2016$ P$1$".

Answer (score 1):

Trying smaller cases we see that nearly always $n|m$ so we try to find solutions in the form $m=kn$ for $k\in \mathbb N$.
Now lets rewrite $\frac{n^m-m^n}{m+n}$ as
$\frac{n^m-m^n}{m+n}=\frac{n^{kn}-(kn)^n}{n(k+1)}=\frac{n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}-k^n)}{k+1}$.
Now we require that $k+1|n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}-k^n)$.
First case is when $n\equiv 1(mod 2)$.We have
$n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}-k^n)\equiv n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}+1)(mod (k+1))$.
Condition $m>n^n$ implies $k>n^{n-1}$.But since
$2|n^{(k-1)n}+1$ we see that $k+1=2n^{n-1}$ works.
So for odd $n$ we have $\boxed{m=(2n^{n-1}-1)n}$.
Second case is when $n\equiv 0(mod2)$,$n>2$. We have
$n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}-k^n)\equiv n^{n-1}(n^{(k-1)n}-1)(mod (k+1))$.
Condition $m>n^n$ implies $k>n^{n-1}$.But since
$p|n-1$ $\implies$ $(p,n)=1$ and $p|n^{(k-1)n}-1$ where $p$ is some prime.
We see that $k+1=pn^{n-1}$ works, where $p$ is prime divisor of $n-1$.
So for $n>2$ even $\boxed{m=(pn^{n-1}-1)n}$ where $p$ is prime divisor of $n-1$.
For $n=2$,$m=5$ works.